# Active camera not working on blender game

Tags: rendering, game-engine, 3d-view, camera

I have a feeling this is a small mistake but I can't trace a solution for it myself. Basically I made a small Resident Evil style room with multiple cameras. I also set up an actuator system to trigger the activation of each camera as active as the character moves in it's respective area. But when I press P for the scene preview it just shows the viewport view instead of the camera views. I'm losing my mind, can someone tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: I think I saw this before... Are you sure your cameras are at the same layer as the rest of your level, and not in hidden layers?

Comment: Yeah, everything is in the same layer

Comment: Add a example file, as I can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=51092 Thanks for the quick answer, here it is

Comment: Currently I'm going to my job right now, so probably I'll only be able to check the file tomorrow, I hope you don't mind waiting.

Comment: its ok, im working on other parts of the game for now, thank you for agreeing to help out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's several issues on you file...

## Character Structure

Try to read the [BGE Guide To Character Setup](https://blenderartists.org/t/prof-monsters-bge-guide-to-character-setup/534869), you will understand that an armature should not be the physics object of your character: make an physics object with physics type *Capsule* and parent the armature to it. Also, make sure to check the *Actor* checkbox, so your player can be detected by the zones.

[image]

## Zones Physics

*Static* objects can't detect collisions, so you have to change your zones physics types to *Sensor* and enable *Detect actors*. Also, disable the pulse mode on the collision sensors, it takes a lot of memory.

[image]

## A Silly Mistake...

Your collision sensors are looking for an object with the property `Player`, but your player does not have this property! Add it to your player and the sensors should detect it.

[image]

## Conclusion

Also, there's a lot of optimization you could do, especially disabling the physics on objects that don't need it (paintings, lamps, statue, etc). Try to read [these guides](https://blenderartists.org/t/monsters-resources/493045) to learn a bit more about logic, structure and project management.

Your file with some of the issues corrected:
[image]

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! Your explanations are very simple and very to the point and I feel so dumb because of the Property thing haha, I put a property on the mesh but not on the armature. I'm reading the guides you linked and applying the project management logic in the other parts of the game.

Comment: Glad it helped you. ;)

Comment: Let me ask you something... Where you from? The file you sent, 'Jaguatirica Ambiente'... Are you brazilian?

Comment: Yes, I'm Brazilian haha. This project is a music video i`m making for a song called Jaguatirica by an indie band called Moblins

Comment: Cool! Join the WhatsApp group of BGE for brazilians, you are welcome. ;) https://chat.whatsapp.com/FIglrhkRtUdAFzn2oKdvZj